# Any issues in MVVM style of application with knockout, html, asmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, mvvm, knockout.js

I had been developing web applications in classic asp in my past. We heard about MVVM styles and knockoutJS. We felt this may improve the client response time better and went ahead in MVVM with the help of knockout,html(in aspx pages) & webservice(asmx) codings.

In all our markups we avoided aspx controls and used html tags with knockout bindings. Only on a necessity to use session states, we write some coding on aspx.cs

However, I am not sure is this the right practice in using MVVM (or) does it have some other disadvantages in using knockout,html and asmx to build the application.

Any comment on this would show a bright way for us.

Comment: I agree this is a opinion based question. However, sharing the experience will let us to know about different design styles, wherein we could choose if something is advantageous.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a good idea to separate the data, the viewmodels, and the view html.

The html for the view (which contains data-bind attributes) should be delivered by asp.net. The viewmodels will contain the client-side business logic and will be stored in separate js files. Then you would use the webservices to send data to the client, preferably delivered as json, for easy deserialization on the client.

The viewmodels will know how to ask for data from the webservices and will also know how to update themselves once the data arrives. If you set your data-bind attributes correctly, the interface will auto-update based on the changes in the viewmodels.

As for the initial state of the page (when it first loads), you could either deliver an initial dataset with the html (just write the json in a js variable in the html), or set a "loading" state on page load, and ask for data from the webservice.

Then you need to decide how much you want your app to behave like a single-page app. Will you actually submit the page to the server very often or make a lot of ajax requests? When we did this in the past with a very large project, we built sections of the application like single-page apps, while other stuff (mostly the boring parts, like user management), were standard forms, with standard submits.

And finally, decide between how much business logic will run inside the webservices (server-side) and how much in the viewmodels (client-side).